# Java to PHP Post not working

Tags: java, php, post

I have been all over trying to figure this out and it won't work. The issue is with the java code because nothing will POST to the website(s), yes I tried multiple hosts and sites. Please help me!
Java:

```
package NewClasswork;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
public class girls
{
    static double bonus;
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        //variable stuff//
        String[] scale = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
        String[] atalk = {"Yes", "Little", "No"};
        JTextField hername = new JTextField("Girl's Name");
        JTextField yourname = new JTextField("Your Name");
        JComboBox hot = new JComboBox(scale);
        JComboBox nice = new JComboBox(scale);
        JComboBox popular = new JComboBox(scale);
        JComboBox talk = new JComboBox(atalk);
        bonus = 0;

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        //panel stuff//
        panel.add(hername);
        panel.add(yourname);
        panel.add(new JLabel("How hot is she?"));
        panel.add(hot);
        panel.add(new JLabel("How nice is she to you?"));
        panel.add(nice);
        panel.add(new JLabel("How popular is she?"));
        panel.add(popular);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Do you talk to her?"));
        panel.add(talk);

        //statement stuff//
        int pane = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Chances with girl", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        if (pane == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
        {
            int nhot = Integer.valueOf((String) hot.getSelectedItem());
            int nnice = Integer.valueOf((String) nice.getSelectedItem());
            int npopular = Integer.valueOf((String) popular.getSelectedItem());
            String hname = hername.getText();
            String yname = yourname.getText();

            if ((String) talk.getSelectedItem() == "Yes")
            {
                bonus = 2;
            }
            else if ((String) talk.getSelectedItem() == "Little")
            {
                bonus = 1.2;
            }
            else if ((String) talk.getSelectedItem() == "No")
            {
                bonus = 0.3;
            }

            double chance = (((11-nhot)+(11-nnice)+(11-npopular)/3)*bonus)+40;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your chances of going out with " + hname + " is %" + chance);

            String strData = encode(hname, yname, nhot);
            submit(strData);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    public static String encode(String urname, String hrname, int nhott) {

        String strToSend;
        String nnhott = Integer.toString(nhott);
        try
        {
            strToSend = URLEncoder.encode("guy", "UTF-8") + "=";
            strToSend += URLEncoder.encode(urname, "UTF-8");
            strToSend += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("girl", "UTF-8") + "=";
            strToSend += URLEncoder.encode(hrname, "UTF-8");
            strToSend += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("rate", "UTF-8") + "=";
            strToSend += URLEncoder.encode(nnhott, "UTF-8");
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            return "Error encoding data for submission";
        }

        return strToSend;
    }

    public static String submit(String strToSend) {

        URL urlDest;
        String strData = strToSend;
        System.out.println(strData);
        HttpURLConnection ucConnect;

        try 
        {
            urlDest = new URL("http://spaderp.com/collin/index.php");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "Error in submitting entry";
        }

        try
        {
            ucConnect = (HttpURLConnection) urlDest.openConnection();
            ucConnect.setRequestProperty("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            ucConnect.setRequestMethod("POST");
            ucConnect.setDoOutput(true);

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "Error in connecting to URL";
        }

        try
        {
            OutputStreamWriter streamWrite = new OutputStreamWriter(ucConnect.getOutputStream());
            streamWrite.write(strData);
            System.out.println(streamWrite.toString());
            streamWrite.flush();

            //Get the response

            ucConnect.getInputStream();
            System.out.println(ucConnect);
            streamWrite.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            return "Problem";
        }

        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        return "Yay!";
    }
}
```

Here is the very simple php part:

```
<?php

$aguy = $_POST["guy"];
$agirl = $_POST["girl"];
$arate = $_POST["rate"];

echo $aguy . ' just submited that he liked ' . $agirl . ' and rated her as a ' . $arate;

print_r($_POST);

?>
```

Also this is the only thing on the website after the java has been run:

```
just submited that he liked and rated her as a Array ( )
```

And Finally, this is the console output from java:

```
    guy=Girl%27s+Name&girl=Your+Name&rate=1
java.io.OutputStreamWriter@2535eea8
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection:http://spaderp.com/collin/index.php
SUCCESS
```

Comment: So the request is getting to the server (because `just submited that he liked and rated her as a Array ( )` comes from your server side PHP). The request may not be as you expect... Have you tried any debugging techniques (firebug or developer tools in firefox - I'm sure there is a chrome equivalent) or proxying traffic via fiddler to see what is happening?

Comment: try the same request with postman REST client on chrome. if you get the correct response the bug is in the java code.

Comment: Are you trying to print the response? (Because you're currently not)

Comment: @CollinCraig I guess that you are trying to check your page right after your request by java is done? are you?